# prestashop - Loading a smarty template in a tab

Tags: php, templates, tabs, smarty, prestashop-1.6

What I'm trying to attempt is to display a template on a custom tab.

This is the code of controllers/admin/AdminTController.php:

```
<?php
class AdminTController extends ModuleAdminController {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function display() {

        //echo $this->l('This is admin my module tab !');
        // the echo works.
        $this->createTemplate('initial.tpl');
    }
}
```

This is code of /views/templates/admin/initial.tpl:

```
<p>This is just a test</p>
```

The result of this code is a blank page.This means the template is not loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below mentioned code.

```
<?php
class AdminTController extends ModuleAdminController {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function display() {
        $tpl = $this->custom_smarty->createTemplate('initial.tpl');
        return $tpl->fetch();
    }
}
?>
```